# Can any one tell why the previous data is still displayed while saving data using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamwriter

I am saving data to a file-name using Stream writer but if i run the code for second time the same data is appended to the previous data but i would like to clear the old data and write the data

The data i should have in text file should be as follows

```
101 435435345 3445454541104021031A094101                                                      
52251               1                   1         CCD1         110402110402   1111000020000001
6281110000251                00000000011              1                     1 0111000020000001
822500000100111000020000000000010000000000001                                  111000020000001
 9000001000001000000010011100002000000000001000000000000
```

My sample code

```
if (i == 0)
{
  index++;
  string m_strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
  m_strDate = m_strDate.Replace("/", "");
  StrFilePath = "log" + m_strDate + index + ".txt";
}
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(StrFilePath,true))
    {
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strLine))))
    {
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
         {
           strReadLine = sr.ReadLine();
          if (strReadLine.StartsWith("1"))
           {
                if (i == 0)
              {
                  strFileHeader = strReadLine;
                  sw.WriteLine(strFileHeader);
               }
          }
   if (strReadLine.StartsWith("5"))
     {
     strBatchHeader = strReadLine;
      if (i == 0)
    {
         Btchno = Convert.ToInt32(strBatchHeader.Substring(87, 7));
        BatchCnt = Convert.ToInt16(Btchno);
       }
     if (i > 0)
    {
           BatchCnt++;
           strBatchHeader = strBatchHeader.Substring(0, 87) + Convert.ToString(BatchCnt.ToString().PadLeft(7, (char)48));
      }
    sw.WriteLine(strBatchHeader);
  }
   }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You should use a `StringReader` instead of your `StreamReader`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing `true` as the **`append`** parameter in the `StringWriter` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter here: `new StreamWriter(StrFilePath,true)` is set to true, which means append to file. Set that parameter to false and it will work.

Comment: If i set to false then i can not write the data as per i required

Comment: @Dora: That is not true.  StreamWriters work fine with the parameter set to false.

Comment: Gerrie assume the output will be same every time in my file as i mentioned but if i set to false and then proceeding i am not getting that